# RegEx to extract first set of digits from a string

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to extract the first set of digits only with regex function  from col A in Vba.

PRECEDEX 200 mcg 2 mL FTV should print only 200. Currently my code prints all the numbers.

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
    Dim Regex As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("E3:E1500")

    For Each C In Myrange
        strPattern = "\D+"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = C.Value
            strReplace = "$1"

            With Regex
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern

            End With

            If Regex.test(strInput) Then
                C.Offset(0, 1) = Regex.Replace(strInput, " ")
            Else
                C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You should just use `\d+` pattern, and use `.Execute` rather than `.Replace` method, to actually *extract* the digits (you also need to use `RegExp.Global=False`).

Comment: It worked @Wiktor Stribiżew. Also. why does .Execute work and .Replace does not?

Comment: `.Replace` with `\D+` removes all non-digit chars, while `.Execute` with `\d+` returns the 1+ digits found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `\d+` pattern, and use `.Execute` rather than `.Replace` method to actually *extract* the digits (you also need to use `RegExp.Global=False` to find only the first match).

Use

```
Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
    Dim Regex As New regexp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim mtch As Object

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("E3:E1500")

    For Each c In Myrange
        strPattern = "\d+"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = c.Value


            With Regex
                .Global = False
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .pattern = strPattern

            End With

            If Regex.test(strInput) Then
                Set mtch = Regex.Execute(strInput)
                If mtch.Count > 0 Then
                    c.Offset(0, 1) = mtch.Item(0).Value
                End If
            Else
                c.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here, `Set mtch = Regex.Execute(strInput)` tries to find the match and if a match is found (`If mtch.Count > 0`), the value (`mtch.Item(0).Value`) is added to the next column on the right.